# Remove trailing slash

Tags: nginx, web-server

I am serving a directory with static content lets say

```
|-index.html
|--a
|  |-index.html
|--b
   |-index.html
```

When I access http://localhost/a - currently it gets a permanent redirect to http://localhost/a/ which serves the http://localhost/a/index.html.

I would like to have same behaviour without the browser url changing from http://localhost/a to http://localhost/a/.

Comment: Technically, access to a directory serving an index should have the closing slash, cause it's a directory index and not a file, though not having one is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try_files`.

For example:

```
try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
```

The first term looks for an exact match (a file matching the URI). The second term looks for a directory containing `index.html`, where the directory path is specified by the URI (without a trailing `/`). Otherwise a 404 response is returned.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.